# If I have both Rails 2.3.8 and 3.0.0 (as gems), can I switch between them easily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

On Ubuntu, if Rails 3.0 was installed using

```
sudo gem install rails
```

and then Rails 2.3.8 was installed later:

```
sudo gem install -v 2.3.8 rails
```

Now the system has both Rails 2.3.8 and 3.0.0.  But if the following is typed into bash:

```
rails -v
```

Then 3.0.0 will show.  Is there a way to switch to using 2.3.8 instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to have a look at the [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) tool and especially its [gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/) feature.

Answer (score 2):

Like was said above for rails 2.3 apps in environment.rb do

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

For rails 3 you use bundler Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
```

That above would be enough **but**

General advise, install rvm.

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

Add this to your ~/.profile.

```
$ [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Now reload the profile so the terminal knows about rvm.

```
$ source .profile
```

Run these.

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2      (this installs ruby 1.9.2-p0, the latest)
$ rvm 1.9.2 --default    (this sets the default implementation of ruby)
$ gem install rails
$ gem install rails -v=2.3.8
```

You would then be good to go, trust me if you don't use rvm you don't know what you are missing. Then as mentioned there are gemsets too look it up here http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `environment.rb` file

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

If you're talking about launching rails executable from shell, then just specify correct path. Once 2.3.8 executable is launched, I don't think it can somehow find and transfer control to 3.0.0 executable.

Comment: `/usr/bin/rails` is the rails 3.0 bin... do you know where 2.3.8 bin is?  thanks.

Comment: @Jian Run _gem env_ and check _GEM PATHS_ section.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a way in the Agile book:

```
rails _2.3.8_ -v
```

and it will say it is version 2.3.8, although I don't know how well this approach works (how well it isolates the 2 versions of Rails) comparing to using RVM.